# Is there an alx driver substitute for ethernet card?

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have Bionic Beaver, kernel 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu on an MSI GE60 laptop with the following Ethernet controller:

```
Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

After a random period of time (especially when I do an RDP session), the kernel starts flooding /var/log/syslog with gigabytes of the following text (hundreds lines per second):

```
May 17 10:08:07 mylaptop kernel: [ 9444.580988] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: fatal interrupt 0x4001607, resetting
```

The entire system gradually stops responding, one of the processor cores is 100% busy and the power-off button is the only way out. I know the problem  emerged a couple of years ago, and was impossible to solve then (eg [Ubuntu 15.04: eth0 is no longer working after last software upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627287/ubuntu-15-04-eth0-is-no-longer-working-after-last-software-upgrade)). My question is, could I install another Ethernet card driver by apt instead of alx?

**Important:** I cannot use the wireless connection.

Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/627287/ubuntu-15-04-eth0-is-no-longer-working-after-last-software-upgrade "Configure the interface with the MTU = 9000"  https://askubuntu.com/questions/761036/ubuntu-16-04-ethernet-issues/770865 "setting the IPv6 settings "Method" section to "ignore"" and the bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761  "AR8161 wir alx driver: Randomly stops to receive packets with small MTU" From the bug: up the MTU to 9000. See the 1st link.

Comment: Unfortunately, MTU 9000 failed to help. The incident happened again after some 2 hours on the net, with rdesktop on. IPv6 "Method" had already been "off" (have no "ignore" option in my Ethernet settings).

Comment: Hi again. @Rinzwind provided me with a possible solution (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761), however I am unable to use it, just don't know what to apply this patch: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=191091